# Web API Multiple actions were found that match the request on POST with only one action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm having an issue where I'm getting the error:Multiple actions were found that match the request on POST on the url /api/v1/audit

I'm confused to how this is happening since I only have one action in the controller. Does anyone know what may be going on?

```
public class AuditController :ApiControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public int Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "FacetApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/${action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Works fine here. Maybe `ApiControllerBase` already implements a conflicting method?

Comment: @Alexander Zeitler only thing in there is an initlaize function

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler only thing in there is an initlaize function